# What OS's work on the Pi-top?

Tags: operating-systems

I have a Pi-top sitting around and was wondering what OS's worked on it. I have the sd card it came with which has something on it but i was wondering if any other OS's would work especially because it has an extra circuit board that it it comes with.

I'm using the older Pi-top not the new Pi-top Ceed, which is more like a Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website doesn't specify a list of supported operating systems, but it looks like it should support anything that runs on the Raspberry Pi.

The screen module gets input from a standard HDMI port and has a special board that abstracts the drivers away from the RPi; the keyboard appears to connect via USB. So, your best bets are to pick something that supports USB device input and HDMI out.

Comment: What's a Pi-top?

Comment: @Ghanima: http://www.pi-top.com/

Comment: beat me to a new tag.

Comment: It would seem as though you were right because it is working.